# Delete and minus data at specific cell from database

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am creating a form page where I need to show data in data grid view. When the user adds any item from the grid view it should be minused from inventory and update inventory when user press add button.

The code that I am using is giving me this exception:

> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '='.

My code:

```
    private void btnMoveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True");
        con2.Open();

        String Query1= "DELETE FROM Inventory WHERE id = " + tbID.Text + "";

        SqlCommand sqlcmd1 = new SqlCommand(Query1, con2);
        sqlcmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Inventory SET Quantity = @Quantity" +"WHERE id= " + tbID, con2);
        sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item", this.nudQuantity.Text);
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con2.Close();
    }
```

Comment: There are no space between ```@Quantity``` and ```WHERE id= ```

Comment: Then i just need to remove spaces?

Comment: `mysql` is not the same as `sql-server`. I removed the `mysql` tag.

Comment: Why are you trying to update an item *after* you delete it?

Comment: and Exception is coming from String Quary1= "DELETE FROM Inventory WHERE id = " + tbID.Text + "";

Comment: i need to decrease its quantity means if its 10 and user selects 5 from it then it should be 5 reaminig

Comment: That does not answer my question.  Start by using SQL Parameters.  Always.  Then, perform data validation on user input.  Also consider a DGV for the display; that is what it was designed for.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you concatenate two strings without space between.

But there are many other errors.

All user values should be a sql parameter with correct type.
`nudQuantity.Text` must be parsed/validated. Maybe `id` too.

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True";

using (var con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    con2.Open();
    var Query1 = "DELETE FROM Inventory WHERE id = @id";

    var sqlcmd1 = new SqlCommand(Query1, con2);
    sqlcmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", tbID.Text);
    sqlcmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

    var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Inventory SET Quantity = @Quantity WHERE id=@id", con2);
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", tbID.Text);
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", int.Parse(nudQuantity.Text));

    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();       
}
```

You could also merge these two query in a single one.

This query should be more like what you need.

```
UPDATE Inventory SET Quantity = Quantity-@Quantity WHERE id=@id;
DELETE FROM Inventory WHERE id = @id AND Quantity <= 0;
```

But there are no check on product availability here. If @Quantity is greater than Quantity, then no error will be thrown.

Comment: now it is giving this exception Additional information: Must declare the scalar variable "@id".

Comment: sorry i am very new to C# and sql i have very basic knowledge

Comment: I have edited the answer. Replaced ```@item``` by ```@id```.

Comment: but now it is just removing the whole row not updating it

Comment: Like @Plutonix says, If you delete the product, the update will do nothing. You must edit the code according to your specifications.

Comment: You should use Sql management studio (or vs with ssdt tools) to create/test your queries. When that work as expected, convert it to c#.

Comment: haha it is updating but removing previous value i need to decrease previous one

Comment: can i store that quantity into a variable then minus it with new one and store it back to the quantity cell again

Comment: Yes. You can use ```DECLARE @q INT = 0``` and ```SELECT @q=quantity ...``````. Plus some if statements. Use ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteNonQuery to get a single value in your c# app.